# Dapper with postgresql error (sequence contains more than one element)

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, dapper

I am getting this error when I run an integration test against my Postgresql DB using a stored procedure.

```
Result Message: System.InvalidOperationException : Sequence contains more than one element
```

Here is the repo file:

```
  public card_view SelectView(int card_id)
        {
            using (var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(ConfigurationSettings.GetConnectionString()))
            {
                var p = new DynamicParameters();
                p.Add("@card_id", card_id);

                using (var multi = connection.QueryMultiple("f_card_select_view", p, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure))
                {
                    card_view view = multi.Read<card_view>().Single();
                    view.Categories = multi.Read<category>().ToList();
                    view.Modifiers = multi.Read<card_modifier_view>().ToList();

                    return view;
                }
            }
        }
```

The card test file:

```
   [Test]
    public void SelectViewTest()
    {
        var repo = new CardRepository();
        var result = repo.SelectView(31);  // witch

        Assert.AreEqual(2, result.Categories.Count);
        Assert.AreEqual(2, result.Modifiers.Count);
    }
```

Cardview file:

```
public class card_view
    {
        public int card_id { get; set; }
        public int cardset_id { get; set; }
        public string cardset_title { get; set; }
        public string image_path { get; set; }
        public string cardset_name { get; set; }
        public int card_cost { get; set; }

        public List<card_modifier_view> Modifiers { get; set; }
        public List<category> Categories { get; set; }
    }
```

cardmodifierview file:

```
public class card_modifier_view
    {
        public int card_modifier_id { get; set; }
        public int card_id { get; set; }
        public int modifier_type_id { get; set; }
        public int? modifier_value { get; set; }
        public string instruction_text { get; set; }
        public string modifier_type_name { get; set; }
    }
```

The DB function (The original SQL was T-SQL and I have done my best to translate it into regular SQL for postgres.)

```
CREATE FUNCTION f_card_select_view (card_id int)
RETURNS TABLE(card_id bigint, modifier_type_id integer, 
instruction_text integer, modifier_type_name integer, card_modifier character varying, modifier_type character varying)
AS $$
SELECT card_id,cardset.cardset_id,card_title,image_path,card_cost,cardset_name
FROM card 
INNER JOIN cardset ON card.cardset_id = cardset.cardset_id
WHERE card_id = @card_id;
SELECT  card.category_id,category_name
FROM category card
INNER JOIN card_category ON card.category_id = card_category.category_id
WHERE card_category.card_id = @card_id;
SELECT f_card_modifier_selectby_card_id (@card_id);
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

Here is f_card_modifier_selectby_card_id:

```
CREATE FUNCTION f_card_modifier_selectby_card_id(card_id int)
RETURNS TABLE(
card_id bigint,
modifier_type_id int,
instruction_text int,
modifier_type_name int,
card_modifier varchar,
modifier_type varchar
)
AS $$

SELECT
card_modifier_id,
card_id,
card_modifier.modifier_type_id,
modifier_value,
instruction_text,
modifier_type_name
FROM card_modifier INNER JOIN modifier_type ON card_modifier.modifier_type_id = modifier_type.modifier_type_id
WHERE card_id = card_id

$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

Comment: you probably missed column order, assigning some char to int or opposite

Comment: just updated with more info. The error is different now. I fixed the return section of the f_card_select_view functions to match f_card_modifier_selectby_card_id.

Answer (score 1):

If the error is `Sequence contains more than one element`, then the problem is that your first query (where you have the `.Single()`) ***is returning more than one row***. I can't tell you why that is, but you need to try running:

```
SELECT card_id,cardset.cardset_id,card_title,image_path,card_cost,cardset_name
FROM card 
INNER JOIN cardset ON card.cardset_id = cardset.cardset_id
WHERE card_id = @card_id;
```

(with your expected `@card_id`) in your SQL toolkit to see what happens. Or better: call the stored procedure itself - *presumably* via:

```
EXEC f_card_select_view {your id here}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your statement brings back a join containing multiple records for card_view or 0.

In other frameworks certainly you can use SingleOrDefault() to allow for 0 records. Note this will still error for multiple records.

If its getting multiple records you need to establish if this is correct and rework it to be a collection like you have done with .ToList() or correct your data in the database and possibly your keys.